# Function with compact support

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $d\geq 1$ and $U \subset \mathbb{R^{d}}$ be open.

For any $K\subset U$, compact, there exists $u_{K} \in C_{0}^{\infty}(U)$ with $u_{K} \geq 0$ such that ${\rm supp  \,}u_{K}=K $ ?

I am looking for the function as mentioned above. Thanks.

Comment: That is not true, take e.g. $K =\{x\}$ for some $x\in U$.

Comment: Depending on what you mean, you might find it helpful to look at "smooth cutoff functions" on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier.  Not quite your original question, but gets close to the spirit of what you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PhoemueX already pointed out, the claim does in general *not* hold. But the following statement is correct:

> Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be compact and $K \subset U$ open. Then there exists $u \in C_0^{\infty}(U)$ such that $u|_{K}=1$.

The result is known as **Urysohn's lemma** and used quite frequently in measure theory.

Comment: Thanks. I will I refer to the textbook.